# Proper lambda syntax for removing elements of the vector

Tags: c++, lambda

ALL,

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
};

void Foo::Remove(const std::string &table)
{
    vec.erase( std::remove_if( vec.begin(), vec.end, [](const std::string &str)
    {
        str.find( table ) != -1;
    }, vec.end() ) );
}
```

How do I proper capture the table parameter inside the lambda? And is my syntax correct?
I need to remove the elements of `vec` that contain the `table`.

TIA!

Comment: If you need to capture `table` in the lambda, you could do `[&]`.

Comment: Also, your lambda needs a `return` statement: `return str.find( table ) != std::string::npos;`